# Where Can I get G722 free source code?

Tags: audio, codec

I have to use G722 source code, can anyone help me to get the free source anywhere?

I have downloaded a src from here http://www.pjsip.org/

but it seems impossible to separate the G722 src from the other included dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get it here:

http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.722-200911-S!AppIV/en

and for any G-series codec, you can get at below path:
http://www.itu.int/net/itu-t/sigdb/speaudio/Gseries.htm

Comment: It got superseded with http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.722/recommendation.asp?lang=en&parent=T-REC-G.722-201209-I

Answer (score 2):

Another possibly useful reference would be the FFmpeg source (ffmpeg.org). Look in the libavcodec/ directory and find the files g722.[ch], g722dec.c and g722enc.c. You probably can't lift the code directly out of those files (and there are licensing issues besides as the code is LGPL). However, the algorithm should be simple enough to adapt based on this example.